# Ruby on Rails: No Migration Scripts are created any longer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, migration, nameerror

I've been working with Rails for 3 Months now, but haven't experienced this problem until now. I'm currently working through Micharl Hartls Tutorial and everything worked fine so far, but suddenly (chapter 11) I can no longer create Migration Files.

When entering "rails g model Name field1:type" I don't get the usual "create db/migrate...." status lines in the console, but instead tons of location links (C:/Programs/Railsinstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/...activesupport".

On the Top it says "Block in cunstantize: uninitialized constant cacher 8NameError)

And no migration files are created in the db folder. I tested the "rails g controller"-command which works fine. Also creating new models /migrations in other projects do work. But creating migrations in this specific "sample_app" is no longer possible and I just don't know why. I couldn't find anything about this problem on the web either. I hope you guys are familiar with this problem and can help me out?

Comment: can you start the server or the console?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
rake secret
```

and put the generated key in your config/initializers/secret_token.rb file in a line like this:

```
RAILS_APP_NAME::Application.config.secret_token = 'YOUR_RAKE_GENERATED_KEY'
```

changing RAILS_APP_NAME by your app name.

and in the file

```
config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

make sure you have a line like this:

```
RAILS_APP_NAME::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_RAILS_APP_NAME_session'
```